# Collect duplicate data in array using php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

> this is my sample array data from bio-metrics
>   I just want to collect data that has the **same bio_id and date**

```
temp:[
0:{
 bio_id:"1"
 date:"2017-10-05"
 date_time:"2017-10-05 08:00:22"
 device_name:"biometrics"
 time:"08:00:22"
}
1:{
 bio_id:"1"
 date:"2017-10-05"
 date_time:"2017-10-05 08:00:23"
 device_name:"biometrics"
 time:"08:00:23"
}
2:{
 bio_id:"2"
 date:"2017-10-05"
 date_time:"2017-10-05 08:06:29"
 device_name:"biometrics"
 time:"08:06:29"
}
3:{
 bio_id:"1"
 date:"2017-10-05"
 date_time:"2017-10-05 15:06:47"
 device_name:"biometrics"
 time:"15:06:47"
}
4:{
 bio_id:"2"
 date:"2017-10-05"
 date_time:"2017-10-05 16:01:50"
 device_name:"biometrics"
 time:"16:01:50"
}
]
```

> I been stuck with this code that I made, and don't know how I should manipulate it, or how I will store it properly, I have try some array function but it gives different result to my data

```
$len = count($temp);
for ($i=0; $i <$len ; $i++) { 
  $id = $temp[$i]['bio_id'];
  $date = $temp[$i]['date'];
 for ($x=0; $x < $len; $x++) { 
   if ($id == $temp[$x]['bio_id'] && $date == $temp[$x]['date']) {
         $data[] = $temp[$x];
         $int[] = $x;
   }
 }
}
```

> I don't know how I should manipulate it, or how I will store it properly, I have try some array function but it gives different result to my data

Comment: try using array_unique() function ...

Comment: I cannot spot any duplicate in the data you posted. Maybe you should define what do you mean by "duplicate" and how looks the expected output.

Comment: @RamuBhusal [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) doesn't help. There are no duplicates in the posted array.

Comment: I just updated my question, sorry for the confusing question

Comment: *"I just want to collect data that has the same **bio_id and date**"* -- what about the other fields? They are different on entries that have the same `bio_id` and `date`. How do you want to store them?

Comment: I will put other code for that @axiac

Comment: will this work?
`$movies = array(
  array(
    "bio_id" => 1,
    date=>"2017-10-05"
  ),
  array(
    "bio_id" => 2,
    date=>"2017-10-05"
  )
);
//print_r($movies);
$x = count($movies);
for ($i = 0; $i<$x; $i++) {
    if ($movies[$i][bio_id]==$movies[$i+1][bio_id]){
          print_r($movies[$i]);
          echo " same";
        }
  if ($movies[$i][date]==$movies[$i+1][date]){
          print_r($movies[$i]);
          echo " same";
        }
}`

Comment: I try it but It has an error

Comment: @mickmackusa .. sorry i thought i posted that on answer :p

Comment: @MariaJen Did you search SO at all before posting: `[php] group multidimensional array` is a good search phrase to start with.

Comment: This is a pretty close duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815660/group-multidimensional-arrays-based-on-two-values-in-php  I'll see if I can find a better one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array: replace all keys with concatenation of two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995054/php-multidimensional-array-replace-all-keys-with-concatenation-of-two-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work to collect duplicate in the array on the basis of id and date

```
$newTemp = array();
foreach($temp as $value){
  $newTemp[$value['id'].'_'.$value['date']][] = $value;  
}
```

Comment: I want to collect the duplicate data, not on removing them

Comment: I have updated the code to collect the duplicate data.

Comment: [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) is not [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: it return only one data

Comment: can I request this in for loop, I just want to manipulate it, and i'm not good in using foreach?

Comment: $newTemp = array();
for($count = 0 ; $count < $count($temp);$count++){
  $newTemp[$value['id'].'_'.$value['date']][] = $value;  
}

Comment: I already translate it to for, and i realize how amazing it is, how come you didn't use if, but all with the same bio_id and date , be in one array?

Comment: Is that a shortcut of if, or what?

Comment: 1_2017-10-05, has this kind of index, how can I change it into 0,1,2

Comment: reiterate the array and change key with index

Comment: $newTemp2 = array() ; foreach($newTemp as $value){  $newTemp2[] = $value  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157006/discussion-between-user2613580-and-mariajen).

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to collect data that has the same `bio_id` and `date`

The easiest way is to iterate over the input array and aggregate the data into a new array, indexed by key generated using the `bio_id` and `date` fields. This way, a duplicate entry can be easily identified because the key already exists in the output array.

```
$input = array(/* the big input array here */);
// Build the output here
$output = array();    
foreach ($input as $item) {
    $key = $item['bio_id'].':'.$item['date'];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $output)) {
        // This is a duplicate
        // Ignore the data, update only the count
        $output[$key]['count'] ++;
    } else {
        // This is the first time this combination is processed
        // Copy the input
        $output[$key] = $item;
        // Keep in 'count' how many times this combination exists in the input
        $output[$key]['count'] = 1;
    }
}
```

Each entry of `$output` is the first entry of `$input` that has the same combination of `bio_id` and `date`. Additional, the value of `count` is the number of entries of `$input` that share that pair of `bio_id` and `date`.

Work on this example if you need to aggregate the data in a different way (keep all duplicates, instead of their number, f.e.).

Another example that keeps the duplicates:

```
// Build the output here
$output = array();    
foreach ($input as $item) {
    $key = $item['bio_id'].':'.$item['date'];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $output)) {
        // This is a duplicate; add it to the list
        $output[$key]['all'][] = $item;
    } else {
        // This is the first time this combination is processed
        // Copy important values (bio_id and date) from the input
        $output[$key] = array(
            'bio_id' => $item['bio_id'],
            'date'   => $item['date'],
            // Store the entire $item into a list
            'all'    => array($item),
        );
    }
}
```

Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) how to access their elements using the [square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) and how to [create or modify their values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: Can I request this in for loop?

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is the natural PHP way to process arrays. `for` cannot be used if the array keys are not consecutive numbers starting with `0`.

Comment: it has an error "unexpected }", it was in the if part, I don't know why it has an error like that

Comment: $input = $temp;
        
        $output = array();

        foreach ($input as $item) {
            $key = $item['bio_id'].':'.$item['date'];

            if (array_key_exists($key, $output) {
                
                $output[$key]['count'] ++;
            } else {
               
                $output[$key] = $item;
                
                $output[$key]['count'] = 1;
            }
        }

Comment: A closing parenthesis was missing in the `if` line. I fixed it now and I added another example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newTemp = array();
for($temp as $value){
  $key = $value->id." ".$value->date;
  if(isset($newTemp[$key])){
    $newTemp[$key] = array_merge($newTemp[$key],$value);
  }else{
    $newTemp[$key] = $value;
  }

}
```